Loop row-wise through data.frame to get array- Simple method?
I am quite new to r, and have been struggling with this code involving loops and arrays.
I have data where each participant responded to 14 items, with responses between 1, -1.
For each participant, I would like to find the sum of the absolute differences between each item response and all other item responses (that is, diff_var1= avg(abs(var1-var2) + abs(var1-var3)...). This should result in 14 new variables, each of which is the mean of 13 absolute difference combinations.
A further complicating requirement is that certain absolute difference combinations should be reverse coded (i.e. *-1).
My original approach was to use three nested loops:
1. for each participant, take their responses for each of the 14 items and add them to a vector.
2. Take the absolute difference (or more correctly, 1 - the absolute difference, for reasons I won't go into here) between each element and the rest of the vector, producing a series of vectors that are stored as rows in the array slice for each participant.
3. Multiply each participant's array slice by a weights matrix, such that some item combinations are reverse coded, as noted above.
4. Set the diagonal of each slice to zero, then sum the columns to create a vector for each participant which contains the summed absolute differences for each response item.
5. Store these vectors in a matrix, with a row for each participant
Reproducible example:
data <-structure(list(participant = c(39496L, 40008L, 39550L, 39530L, 
39956L, 39941L), verdict = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), clim_pre_agree = c(1, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333
), gova_pre_agree = c(0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, -0.666666666666667, 
1, 0, 0.333333333333333), joba_pre_agree = c(-0.666666666666667, 
0, 0, -1, 0, -0.666666666666667), longa_pre_agree = c(-1, 0, 
0.666666666666667, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0), hypa_pre_agree = c(-1, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
-0.666666666666667), oppa_pre_agree = c(0.333333333333333, 0, 
0.333333333333333, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333), 
    equitya_pre_agree = c(-0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
    0, 0.666666666666667, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333
    ), resp_pre_agree = c(0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
    -0.333333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667
    ), govb_pre_agree = c(0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667
    ), jobb_pre_agree = c(1, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 
    1, 0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667), longb_pre_agree = c(1, 
    0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, -1, -0.333333333333333, 
    -0.666666666666667), hypb_pre_agree = c(0.666666666666667, 
    -0.333333333333333, -0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.666666666666667, 1), oppb_pre_agree = c(1, 0, -0.666666666666667, 
    1, -0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667), equityb_pre_agree = c(1, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667), clim_post_agree = c(1, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.666666666666667, 1, 0, 0.666666666666667), gova_post_agree = c(0.666666666666667, 
    -0.333333333333333, -0.666666666666667, 1, -0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333), joba_post_agree = c(-0.666666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 0, -1, 0, -0.666666666666667), longa_post_agree = c(0.666666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667), hypa_post_agree = c(0.333333333333333, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
    -0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667), oppa_post_agree = c(-0.333333333333333, 
    0, 0.666666666666667, 1, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333
    ), equitya_post_agree = c(-1, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667), 
    resp_post_agree = c(0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
    -0.333333333333333, 1, 0.333333333333333, -0.666666666666667
    ), govb_post_agree = c(0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333
    ), jobb_post_agree = c(1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    1, 0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667), longb_post_agree = c(0.333333333333333, 
    -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, -1), hypb_post_agree = c(1, -0.333333333333333, 
    -0.333333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667
    ), oppb_post_agree = c(0.333333333333333, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
    0, -0.666666666666667, -1), equityb_post_agree = c(1, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

This is what I have tried so far:
# Produce weights matrix
weight = c(+1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
weightMat = weight %*% t(weight)

arrayData = array(data = NA, dim = c(14, 14, nrow(data)))

finalMeanScore = c()  

for (numberOfParticipants in 1:nrow(data)) {
  # Extract the participant's data
  tempData = unlist(as.vector(data[numberOfParticipants, c("clim_pre_agree", "gova_pre_agree", "oppa_pre_agree", 
                                                           "longa_pre_agree", "joba_pre_agree", "hypa_pre_agree", 
                                                           "equitya_pre_agree", "resp_pre_agree", "govb_pre_agree", 
                                                           "oppb_pre_agree", "longb_pre_agree", "jobb_pre_agree", 
                                                           "hypb_pre_agree", "equityb_pre_agree")]))
  
  for (i in 1:length(tempData)) {
    tempCoh = 1 - abs(tempData[i] - tempData)
    arrayData[i,, numberOfParticipants] = tempCoh
  }
  
  diag(arrayData[,,numberOfParticipants]) <- 0
  
  arrayData[,,numberOfParticipants] <- arrayData[,,numberOfParticipants] %*% weightMat
}

meanMatrix = matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(data), ncol = ncol(arrayData[,,1]))

for (numberOfParticipants in 1:nrow(data)) {
  meanMatrix[numberOfParticipants, ] = colMeans(arrayData[,, numberOfParticipants], na.rm = TRUE)
}


However, I don't think this is working. Each participant ends up with the same absolute value across each item.
I'm trying to develop my skills with r coding, so any pointers or suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

You may use dist for this (just try as.matrix(dist(data[1, cols]))) and use apply on the "data.frame" converted to a "matrix". (The reason to use a "matrix" is, that row-wise operations on "data.frame"s are inherently slow.)
Instead of using a weight matrix, multiply the matrix instantly by the weight vector and transpose.
In a second step create an array with dim = [length(cols), length(cols), nropw(data)] and give a list of appropriate dimension names.
> w <- c(rep(1, 7), rep(-1, 7))
> dm <- dim(data[cols])
> A <- apply(as.matrix(data[cols]), 1, \(x) t(as.matrix(dist(x))*w)) |> 
+   array(c(dm[2], dm[2], dm[1]), list(cols, cols, data$participant))

Result
> A[1:3, , 1:2]
, , 39496

               clim_pre_agree gova_pre_agree oppa_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree      0.0000000      0.3333333      0.6666667
gova_pre_agree      0.3333333      0.0000000      0.3333333
oppa_pre_agree      0.6666667      0.3333333      0.0000000
               longa_pre_agree joba_pre_agree hypa_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree        2.000000       1.666667       2.000000
gova_pre_agree        1.666667       1.333333       1.666667
oppa_pre_agree        1.333333       1.000000       1.333333
               equitya_pre_agree resp_pre_agree govb_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree          1.666667     -0.6666667     -0.3333333
gova_pre_agree          1.333333     -0.3333333      0.0000000
oppa_pre_agree          1.000000      0.0000000     -0.3333333
               oppb_pre_agree longb_pre_agree jobb_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree      0.0000000       0.0000000      0.0000000
gova_pre_agree     -0.3333333      -0.3333333     -0.3333333
oppa_pre_agree     -0.6666667      -0.6666667     -0.6666667
               hypb_pre_agree equityb_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree     -0.3333333         0.0000000
gova_pre_agree      0.0000000        -0.3333333
oppa_pre_agree     -0.3333333        -0.6666667

, , 40008

               clim_pre_agree gova_pre_agree oppa_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree      0.0000000      0.3333333      0.6666667
gova_pre_agree      0.3333333      0.0000000      0.3333333
oppa_pre_agree      0.6666667      0.3333333      0.0000000
               longa_pre_agree joba_pre_agree hypa_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree       0.6666667      0.6666667      0.0000000
gova_pre_agree       0.3333333      0.3333333      0.3333333
oppa_pre_agree       0.0000000      0.0000000      0.6666667
               equitya_pre_agree resp_pre_agree govb_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree         0.3333333      0.0000000      0.0000000
gova_pre_agree         0.0000000     -0.3333333     -0.3333333
oppa_pre_agree         0.3333333     -0.6666667     -0.6666667
               oppb_pre_agree longb_pre_agree jobb_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree     -0.6666667      -0.3333333     -1.0000000
gova_pre_agree     -0.3333333       0.0000000     -0.6666667
oppa_pre_agree      0.0000000      -0.3333333     -0.3333333
               hypb_pre_agree equityb_pre_agree
clim_pre_agree     -1.0000000         0.0000000
gova_pre_agree     -0.6666667        -0.3333333
oppa_pre_agree     -0.3333333        -0.6666667


Data:
cols <- c("clim_pre_agree", "gova_pre_agree", "oppa_pre_agree", "longa_pre_agree", 
"joba_pre_agree", "hypa_pre_agree", "equitya_pre_agree", "resp_pre_agree", 
"govb_pre_agree", "oppb_pre_agree", "longb_pre_agree", "jobb_pre_agree", 
"hypb_pre_agree", "equityb_pre_agree")


Thanks very much for taking the time to help out with this.
These are not functions I am familiar with, so I'm not sure if this does what I need it to. It seems like you use rep() to create a weights vector then create a 14x14 matrix using dim().
I am unclear on the function you are applying across rows in the second last line. What does '(x)' do here? Am I right in thinking the next part uses the dist() function to compute a distance matrix from a transposed version of the original dataframe?

@AidanRM The functions used are fairly basic, you should make an effort to read the documentation using e.g. ?rep, ?dim, etc. work through the small examples there and report back if you still have problems to understand the code. Weights: It's stated that a weight vector was used and no matrix. \(x) is shorthand for function(x), and |> is R's own pipe, similar to the %>% pipe from the magrittr package; this apparently doesn't throw any errors, but if it does, update R.

This may not answer your question and apologies if I miss the plot completely here but using tidyverse functions should be preferable due to parsimony and speed. Note how I also separate the functions onto their own lines that eases error tracking if needed.
Code:
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  
  # A more informative format for your data is the tibble
  
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    
    # Best to change 'participant' to a string/character
    
    participant =
      as.character(participant),
    
    # Select the column indices associated to 'pre' responses, sum them for each row and subtract the summed value from '1'
    
    pre_resp = 
      1 - sum(
        across(3:16)), 
    post_resp = 
      1 - sum(
        across(17:30)), 
    
    # We obviously want to do this for each participant so specify grouping within 'mutate()'
    
    .by = participant) %>% 
  select(participant, pre_resp, post_resp)

Result
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  participant pre_resp post_resp
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>
1 39496          -3.33    -0.333
2 40008          -2.33     1.33 
3 39550           1       -1.67 
4 39530          -7.67     0.667
5 39956          -2.33     2    
6 39941           1.67     1.33  


Thanks for this Rion, I appreciate you taking the time to provide some guidance. Definitely interested in a tidyverse-based solution if possible.
This solution is not quite what I was hoping to achieve, I've edited my original post to clarify my aim.
